# Nested json parse and retrun a key from all loop

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a nested JSON. I want to fetch a key from all loop.Key name is sensors.Finally i want to fetch all the sensors name and values from the json

```
    var p= "{
   "info":{
      "23423424234":{
         "id":"23423424234",
         "sensors":{
            "2523532523":{
               "Name":"test",
               "Frequency":"1"
            },
            "46546456456":{
               "Name":"test1",
               "Frequency":"5"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "vol":{
      "568768678678":{
         "id":"568768678678",
         "sensors":{
            "67867867867":{
               "Name":"test1",
               "Frequency":"1"
            },
            "65474574754":{
               "Name":"test8",
               "Frequency":"5"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}"
```

I tried below code

```
JToken.Parse(pp).SelectTokens("$..sensors").ToList();
            foreach (var tt in sizes)
            {
                   foreach(var ty in tt)
                   {
                       foreach (JProperty prop in ty.Properties())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
                        }
                   }
               

            }
```

but it got stuck in final loop and i can't able to fetch Name and frequency from each loop

Comment: What do you mean by "nested JSON", exactly? Usually that means JSON-in-a-string-in-JSON, but I don't see that in your example. Is the `var p = @ {` meant to be your JSON file? If so, that isn't actually JSON, that's just JavaScript - and you can't parse JavaScript with JSON.NET.

Comment: nested means arranged in a hierarchical structure

Comment: i can parse string value in JToken.Parse(pp).SelectTokens("$..sensors").ToList();its a mistake .i will edit

Comment: Does this JSON format fix? or are there any chances that sensors could be at other level?

Comment: dynamic json format.may in next level also

Comment: @vct That's not what "nested" means in common parlance, sorry. Almost every JSON document is hierarchical (JSON-objects-in-arrays-in-objects-in-other-objects-etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
public class Sensor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
}
```

```
        var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
        var sensorsToken = JToken.Parse(json).SelectTokens("$..sensors").ToList();
        var sensorJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sensorsToken);
        var sensorsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, Sensor>>>(sensorJson);

        sensorsList.ForEach(d =>
        {
            foreach (var sensor in d.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Parent Info: {d.Keys.First()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {sensor.Name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Frequency: {sensor.Frequency}");
            }
        });
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]